# javascript one line nested if else error ": expected"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I want to nested if else statement for href in reactjs but I got an syntax error ": expected". Here is my code:

```
href = {!this.props.activeLanguage ? "https://m.facebook.com/asd1/" : {this.props.activeLanguage.code == "en" ? "https://m.facebook.com/asd1/" : "https://m.facebook.com/asd2/"}}
```

The reason I check active Language at first it comes undefined.

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: `(!this.props.activeLanguage || this.props.activeLanguage.code == "en") ? "https://m.facebook.com/asd1/" : "https://m.facebook.com/asd2/"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inner `{}`, that is object syntax and it is not a valid object. If you need to add grouping use `()` instead.

```js
href = {!this.props.activeLanguage ? "https://m.facebook.com/asd1/" : this.props.activeLanguage.code == "en" ? "https://m.facebook.com/asd1/" : "https://m.facebook.com/asd2/"}
```